# Can any one help When does such error occur ?Project Dotnet core angular 2

Tags: angular

```
Error: [0]/</</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8189/js/zone.js:276:18
    [0]/</</Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:8189/js/zone.js:160:25
    scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:8189/js/zone.js:556:53
    [0]/</</Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8189/js/zone.js:309:22
    [0]/</</Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8189/js/zone.js:198:29
    drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:8189/js/zone.js:452:26
    ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:8189/js/zone.js:383:26

Evaluating http://localhost:8189/app/bundle.js
Error loading http://localhost:8189/app/bundle.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are using the right version of zone.js, npm, and node.

Please paste a plunkr or repo link for more help.